# Datepicker Not Showing On Magento2 Checkout Page On Selection Of Store Pickup Shipment Method

Tags: magento2, checkout, datepicker

Getting error like this on console while clicking on date.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at $.datepicker._showDatepicker (calendar.js:543:50)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5430:49)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:5234:47)
$.datepicker._showDatepicker @ calendar.js:543
dispatch @ jquery.js:5430
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:5234
```

[image]

As per above image, clicking on input box of date. Datepicker was not loading.

How this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're required to modify the file : `<magento-root>/lib/web/mage/calendar.js`

Find below function : probably on line : 541.

```
$.datepicker._showDatepicker = function (input) {
        if (!input.disabled) {
            $.datepicker._showDatepickerOriginal.call(this, input);
        }
    };
```

Replace `$.datepicker._showDatepickerOriginal.call(this, input);` with below code.

```
if ($.datepicker._showDatepickerOriginal != undefined) {
    $.datepicker._showDatepickerOriginal.call(this, input);
} else {
    $.datepicker._showDatepicker.call(this, input);
}
```

don't override lib file, you're supposed to override it in the theme file.

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/web/mage/calendar.js
```

redeploy static files or `rm -r ./pub/static/frontend/**/*`  if developer mode enabled.